# Playing mp3 using java VLC library

Tags: java, android, vlc, acm-java-libraries

How to how the how is suppose to be the how and how lol! you shouldn't be reading this......

Comment: VLC recommend using only formats that do not support the Google APIs, if you want to play only mp3 can use MediaPlayer included in the android SDK , I wrote an example using spotify api https://github.com/erikcaffrey/SpotifyMVP I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

FOR ANDROID APP:

Using the vlc-sdk.7z (libVLC for android) you can embed VLC into your android app or you can use the library vlc-android-sdk from
github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk
which was used in the tomahawk-android music player with its source code avaliable at;
https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk-android

FOR DESKTOP APPS:

You can download the vlcj library version 3.0.1 from their mvn repository here;
mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/3.0.1
OVO Multimedia uses vlcj to play media files and its source code is available at;
https://github.com/Ovoke/OVO-Multimedia

To get mp3 files from within your jar you need to use getResource

Example, assuming song.mp3 is in the root of your jar file and not in a directory:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("song.mp3");
```

Comment: Sir, i really need to be spoon fed im actually really newbie to this. i will flag this as helpful once i find the answer. I am using netbeans sir it for a desktop application. i just want it to play mp3 with stop, resume, play.. i have search everywhere nothing can play what is inside the .jar file. i would really appreciate it if you can help.